# My panel linear regression with log variables returns error on non-finite values, but there are no logs on zero or negative values

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a fixed effects regression in my panel data (using plm package). The regression on levels worked well, so as the first regressions using log variables (I'm putting log on only the dependent and some independent variables, which are in monetary terms). However, my regressions with logs stopped working.

```r
require (AER)
library (AER)
require(plm)
library("plm")

#Indicates the panel and the time and individual columns
dd <- pdata.frame(painel, index = c ('Estado', 'Ano'))

#Model 1 - Model within with individual fixed effects

mod_1_within <- plm(PIB ~ txinad + op + desoc + Divliq + Esc_15 + RT + DC + DK + Gini + I(DK*Gini) + I(DC*Gini), data = dd, effect = 'individual')
summary (mod_1_within)

#this worked well

#Model 2 - Model 1 with the monetary variables in log (the others are % or indexes):

mod_1_within_log<- plm(log(PIB) ~ txinad + log(RT) + op + desoc + Divliq + Esc_15 + log(DC) + log(DK) + Gini + I(Gini*log(DC)) + I(Gini*log(DK)), data = dd, effect = 'individual')
summary (mod_1_within_log)

#This returns:

> mod_1_within_log<- plm(log(PIB) ~ txinad + log(RT) + op + desoc + Divliq + Esc_15 + log(DC) + log(DK) + Gini + I(Gini*log(DC)) + I(Gini*log(DK)), data = dd, effect = 'individual')
Error in model.matrix.pdata.frame(data, rhs = 1, model = model, effect = effect,  : 
  model matrix or response contains non-finite values (NA/NaN/Inf/-Inf)
> summary (mod_1_within_log)
Error in summary(mod_1_within_log) : object 'mod_1_within_log' not found
```

This is ocurring even though there are no log variables with negative or zero values. I will take this opportunity to ask another question: if there is a variable with a zero value, is there a way I can make that value null and them take the log of that variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The log of NA is still NA. - Which makes sense, if you think about it.

Comment: What can I do to correct this?

Comment: `NA` means the value is unknown - there is nothing you can do about it. You will have to remove the row or impute the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the reason why you're getting that error might be that you have `Inf` or `-Inf` values logged predictors or logged outcomes.
In order to check whether that is the case see the untransformed variables (before log) and check whether any observation has a value of `zero`. If it does, that is the problem. Why? R returns `Inf` from `log(0)`. So when you run the FE model, `plm` is giving you that error because it can't deal with `NAN or` `Inf` values.